# How to set the version number using System.CommandLine

Tags: c#

I am using `System.CommandLine` in my command line app. I have am able to set the different options but I don't know how to set the version of the app (it simply displays 1.0.0 when I run it). I read through Microsoft's docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) but found nothing mentioning how to set the version of the executable when compiling or as a setting.

This is my current code:

```cs
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    /* ARGS:
        * HTML_FOLDER;
        * PDFS_FOLDER;
        * names {separated by ;}
        * threads (optional)
    */

    var HTMLS_FOLDER_option = new Option<string>(
        new string[] { "-htmls", "--html-folder" },
            "Where the HTML files are stored");

    var PDFS_FOLDER_option = new Option<string>(
        new string[] { "-pdfs", "--pdf-folder" },
        "Where the PDF files are stored");

    var names_option = new Option<string>(
        new string[] { "-names" },
        "List of names separated by a semi colon (e.g. John Doe; Jane Doe)");

    var threads_option = new Option<int>(
        new string[] { "-threads" },
        "Number of threads (default = 2)");

    var rootCommand = new RootCommand("Converts HTMLs to PDFs provided the names of the files")
    {
        HTMLS_FOLDER_option,
        PDFS_FOLDER_option,
        names_option,
        threads_option
    };

    rootCommand.SetHandler(
        (HTMLS_FOLDER_value, PDFS_FOLDER_value, names_value, threads_value) =>
        {
            OnHandle(HTMLS_FOLDER_value, PDFS_FOLDER_value, names_value, threads_value);
        },
        HTMLS_FOLDER_option, PDFS_FOLDER_option, names_option, threads_option);

    var commandLineBuilder = new CommandLineBuilder(rootCommand)
        .UseDefaults();
    var parser = commandLineBuilder.Build();
    return await parser.InvokeAsync(args).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Mushroomator That was it exactly ! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take this from the [`<Version>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#descriptive-properties) property in the `.csproj` file.

For details on what all the different version numbers (`<FileVersion>`, `<VersionSuffix>`, `<PackageVersion>` etc. ) mean you can check this [blog post by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/version-vs-versionsuffix-vs-packageversion-what-do-they-all-mean/) which goes into detail.